# Link tag is ignored in asp.net dynamic data master page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm getting mad. Site.master page contains the following line within head tag. When the project starts I can see in firebug Net panel that this line is ignored. Even I don't get 404 not Found error;

```
<link href='<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/NewStyles/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css")%>' type="text/css" />
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a pound sign and call Page.Header.DataBind

```
<link href='<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~/NewStyles/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css")%>>' type="text/css" />
```